# LaTeX newcommand with fontname as parameter

Tags: macros

Since I want to display several fonts I my document showing an example of the alphabet of each font I wanted to define a new command to easily get the alphabet; the code for this is the following:

```
\newcommand{\alphabetExample}{{\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont Aa\-Bb\-Cc\-Dd\-Ee\-Ff\-Gg\-Hh\-Ii\-Jj\-Kk\-Ll\-Mm\-Nn\-Oo\-Pp\-Qq\-Rr\-Ss\-Tt\-Uu\-Vv\-Ww\-Xx\-Yy\-Zz\-0123456789}}
```

However, the `#1` isn't accepted - the command works if I write a specific font family instead of the argument.
Thanks for any help, it would really save me a lot of copy-paste-work.

PS: Sorry if the tag isn't right, it's my first question here and I didn't know which one to use.

Comment: `\newcommand{\alphabetExample}[1]` you need to tell LaTeX that the number of arguments of the command.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much ^_^. I've started LaTeX only one week ago so I haven't got familiar with it so far.

Comment: @Manuel. Provided that it was the solution, put it as an answer, so that others may profit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell LaTeX hoy many arguments the command has with `[n]`, in this case just one `[1]`.

```
\newcommand*\alphabetExample[1]
  {{\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont Aa\-Bb\-Cc\-Dd\-Ee\-Ff\-Gg\-Hh\-Ii\-Jj\-Kk\-Ll%
    \-Mm\-Nn\-Oo\-Pp\-Qq\-Rr\-Ss\-Tt\-Uu\-Vv\-Ww\-Xx\-Yy\-Zz\-0123456789}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell TeX how many parameters (and maybe their separators) is provided by the defined macro.

```
\def\alphabetExample#1{%
   {\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont Aa\-Bb\-Cc\-Dd\-Ee\-Ff\-Gg\-Hh\-Ii\-Jj\-Kk\-Ll%
    \-Mm\-Nn\-Oo\-Pp\-Qq\-Rr\-Ss\-Tt\-Uu\-Vv\-Ww\-Xx\-Yy\-Zz\-0123456789}}
```

Comment: But in LaTeX it is better to use `\newcommand` or `\newcommand*` when possible. [Naturally that's not so with alternative formats, and I know you eschew LaTeX.]